# How to access DOM element when using rails partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an html with javascript inside that uses rails partial. I couldn't get the element from rails partial vs if I put the button without using rails partial I am able to get it working.

```
<%= render 'common_component_a', text: 'hello world', elmid: 'grab-this'%>
<script>
  if (document.getElementById('grab-this')) {
    document.getElementById('grab-this').onclick = function() {
     ...
    };
  }
</script>
```

Inside my `common_component_a` I have a section with some css styles

```
<section>
  <span> Part A </span>
  <button id=<%= elmid %>><%= text %></button>
</section>
```

Comment: You really should just consider using classes instead of ids and placing this code in a JS file in your assets pipeline. This seems very much like a self-inflicted problem.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you miss quotes around *id* tag?

```js
<button id="<%= elmid %>"><%= text %></button>
```

Comment: Unquoted attribute-value syntax is fully valid in HTML5. I doubt the author is using XHTML.